# Long string attached and I want to shrink it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have in our site. 
The error is the most obviously Client activity - "`Kundenaktivität`" and at the end this long string which is attached inside. So I want to not see the image below with this long string "`asdasdaxcasdasdasasdasdaxcasdasdasdasdasdasdacasascasc`". Do you know how I can do this ? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4krbR.jpg)
This is attached when a customer comas and clicks on inside a canvas on a new phase. 
This is the code snippet that is used inside the phase.

```js
var Cockpit = {};

Cockpit.CjmCanvas.setMapTableCjHeader = function()
{
    var canvasCjRow = $('#map-table .mm-canvas-cj');
    var headerElements = $('.map-table-header');
    headerElements.each(function() {
        var cxId = $(this).data("id");
        var curEl = canvasCjRow.find(".map-table-col-"+cxId);
        $(this).find(".map-table-cj-col").html(curEl.find(".map-table-displayfield").parent().html());
        if (curEl.find(".phase-arrows-last-element-cj").length == 0) {
            $(this).find(".map-table-menu-icon-cj").remove();
        }
        if ($(this).find('.cjmp-change-cb').length > 0) {
            var select = $(this).find('.cjmp-change-cb');
            var selOption = select.find(':selected');
            select.on("change", function() {
                if (!confirm($(this).data("confirm"))) {
                    selOption.prop("selected", "selected");
                }
            });
        }
      //With this part I tried to add this title to be smaller, but i couldn't pin point the right text (nesto)
        $('.cjmp-drag-element-content').on("click", function(){
            var title = $(".cjmp-drag-element-content span:last-child").text();
            var newTitle = title.substring(0, 5);
            var nesto = $(".cjmp-drag-element-content span:last-child").text(newTitle + "...");
            return nesto;
        });
        $('.mm-canvas-cj').remove();
    });
    $('#canvas-cj').parent().remove();
};
```

```css
#map-table-box #map-table .map-table-header-row .corner-ca span {
    line-height: normal !important;
    max-height: 38px;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 10px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

element {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 110%;
    width: 135px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    height: 27px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cjmp-drag-element-content cjmp-choosen">
  <span class="cjm-score-value" style="background-color: #75EA00;">8.6</span>
  <span class="cjmp-content-visitors" id="cjmpc-visitors-210">0%</span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 220%; width: 135px; padding: 2px 4px; height:27px;">testaasdfasdf </span>
</div>
```

Those are totally two different `css's`. Element is an element which is described in the HTML, and the `map-table-displayfield` is the `css` for the display which is displayed every time someone clicks on canvas. Canvas is shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use a truncate method by setting `max-width` and `overflow` ellipsis like this:

```
.limit-length {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can turn off the `text-overflow: ellipsis`, and optionally nest another object for the text with this class which would allow the arrow to stay in place

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply rfornal. Nice solution, but unfortunately I can't because the arrow on the right side is added afterwards, which means that this arrow is not there when I add Your code to CSS.

Comment: You can turn off the `text-overflow: ellipsis`, and optionally nest another object for the text with this class that would allow the arrow to stay in place.

Comment: Thanks, I have used just like you said in the comment below.

Comment: I'll add the comment to the answer ... glad I could help!